# cross-section a regular quadrangular pyramid

Tags: solid-geometry

A regular quadrangular pyramid  has a regular pentagon cross-section and the side length of the regular pentagon is known to be $a$. How to find the volume of the pyramid?
[image]

Is it possible to find the volume of the pyramid? If yes, how to do it?